# Adding a Series to DataFrame results in strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

My train set is 307,511 rows and test set is 48,744. I combined them into one dataframe (named 'data') which is 356255 rows.

I created a series that flags whether an item belongs to train or test set.

```
trainlen = pd.Series([1]*len(train)+[0]*len(test))
```

Its length is 356255, as expected.

When I add it to the dataset I get strange behavior:

```
data = pd.concat([train,test])
data['isTrain'] = trainlen
```

While `trainlen.sum()` returns 307,511 (as it should), `data.isTrain.sum()` returns 356,255.

It's only when I use 'values':

```
data['isTrain'] = trainlen.values
```

That `data.isTrain.sum()` returns 307511.

Can you explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the indexes. When you use the `concat` method for the two dataframes the indexes will be concatenated generating something like this for your df's index:

```
[0, 1, 2, ..., 307510, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 48743]
```

As you can see the indexes are starting from 0 again at some point. But because also your series has indexes, when you do the assignment like this:

```
data['isTrain'] = trainlen # I am doing an assignment with a Series object that contains also indexes!
```

the data in the series will match only the indexes present in your dataframe, generating a list of only '1's. (**for your series, the values matching the indexes [0, 1, 2, 3, ... 48743] are '1's**)

your df will be something like this

```
        inst  isTrain
0          0        1
1          1        1
2          2        1
3          3        1
4          4        1
...      ...      ...
48739  48739        1
48740  48740        1
48741  48741        1
48742  48742        1
48743  48743        1
```

Can you see that the indexes are wrong? But if you change the indexes of your df before the assignment it will work:

```
data.index = [i for i in range(len(data))] # here I am changing\resetting the indexes
data['isTrain'] = trainlen

print(trainlen.sum())
print(data.isTrain.sum())
```

now indexes and values are correct!

```
         inst  isTrain
0           0        1
1           1        1
2           2        1
3           3        1
4           4        1
...       ...      ...
356250  48739        0
356251  48740        0
356252  48741        0
356253  48742        0
356254  48743        0
```

When you use `trainlen.values` instead, **you are not using the series indexes**. So you are safe in the assignment!

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanations.
I learned a lot.